# SharePoint loading time optimization and caching

Tags: sharepoint, caching, optimization, sharepoint-2010

We have this page in SharePoint that list all the sites, the person who manages that site, their contact info, and the last modified date.

Currently, we are using a custom webpart that crawls through the sites and reads through the metadata, and then it displays all these in a list.

Opening this page takes about 10+ seconds.

We're looking at ways to cut this time to less than 3 seconds.

I'm thinking about some sort of timer job that caches the page, say every half hour, and when the page is requested, simply display the cached version. The data in the page itself doesn't change that often so caching isn't really a big issue. Is this idea feasible? I'm fairly new in SharePoint so what would be the steps to implement this?

Or if there are any other options/suggestions on how to reduce the load time, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here are some approaches that might work for you.

1. Extend your existing Webpart with a cache. So the first User who visit the Site will wait as long as with the existing Solution. But he will fill the cache, so every other call of the Site will be much faster
   [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.webpart.partcachewrite(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.webpart.partcachewrite%28v=office.15%29.aspx)
2. Create a Timer-Job that fill up da extra SharePoint- List with the fields you need. So you render your Webpart using this data. To fetch the needed data from the List will be much faster than iterating some SPWeb or SPSite Objects.
3. A lot of data already can be fetched from the Search-Service, and you can extend the Attributes the search engine will crawl. Once the search attributes are extended you can create a search driven Webpart 
   [http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/jj679900(v=office.15).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/jj679900%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Each of this Solutions should work at SP 2007/10/13

If you need a quick-win than mybee Solution 1 is the best for you.

Regards